# Unable to create a constant value of type 'TravelAgent'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#

I am getting an error and I cant seem to figure out how to solve it.
The error : `Unable to create a constant value of type 'TravelAgent'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

```
public class TravelAgent
    {
        public string SalesOwnerId { get; set; }
        public string AgentId { get; set; }
    }
    var result = db.TRAVEL_AGENT.Where(x => TravelAgents.Any(f=>f.AgentId == x.AgentId && f.SalesOwnerId == x.SalesOwnerId)).ToList();

    dataGridView2.DataSource = result;
```

List TravelAgents, contains instance of TravelAgent.
I want to get all rows from Travel_Agent where I can find the same AgentId and SalesOwnerId that I have in my list.

I know if I take a ToList() before doing this where query then it will succeed but I cant do that because that will return like 500 000 posts.

The error occurs at the where statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Think how you would do that in raw sql and you'll understand what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking for a multi-column JOIN between data in SQL and data in memory, which isn't simple.  Outside of EF you could pass the two lookup columns as a table variable, but EF does not support that to my knowledge.  One option would be to concatenate the columns into one string array that can be used in SQL via an `IN` clause:

```
var lookups = TravelAgents.Select(f=>f.AgentId + "|" + f.SalesOwnerId);

var result = db.TRAVEL_AGENT
               .Where(x => lookups.Contains(x.AgentId + "|" + x.SalesOwnerId))
               .ToList();
```

However, since it's unlikely that you have an index on the string concatenation of the two columns, the query may not be very efficient.

Another option is to get a list of `AgentId`s from `TravelAgents` to filter in SQL, then do the multi-column comparison in C#.  If you eliminate *most* of the unmatched data that way, then it may be the most efficient route.